# How could i paly a video & audio file on an asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

How could i paly a video & audio file on an asp.net page so that the file is determined on the run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET itself has no capabilities to do this as it's a server side technology. What you can do however is put html, just like like you would do in a standard html file, to display these.

If you can already make use of html5 then you're in luck as it provides dedicated tags like [`<video>`](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp) and [`<audio>`](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this in ASP.NET myself, I'd use one of the jQuery plug-ins that make this easy. Check out the [jQuery Media Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/media/) as an example.